# convert string to date in C#

Tags: c#, date

How can I convert a date in a string to a DateTime type, even when the date does not conform to what the .net library supports.

```
"dec 2 2009" 
"dec 2, 2009"
"dec 2009"
"december 2009"
"dec. 2009"
"dec. 2, 2009"
and so on
```

is there a library for this?

assume us date format

Comment: Allowing free format specification of date is problematic. There is no unambiguous parse for 2009/10/9 i.e. when the day is 12 or less you won't be able to distinguish between month and day.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", null);
```

...or whatever the appropriate date format is...

Reference: [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Comment: the problem is i don't know what the user will enter.

Comment: Then use regexes to determine what format the date was provided in, and supply that format to the ParseExact.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the DateTime.ParseExact at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx coupled with the custom formats at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx.

Here's an example:

```
...
DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "%M %d yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out resultDateTime)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

if i understand your question

you can try with

[ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)

E.g :  `DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, "mm/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 0):

"even when the date does not conform to what the .net library supports."

"is there a library for this?"

So you want a library, for when the library doesn't support it?

Obviously, people have probably written other date/time string parsers before, but none of them is going to be exhaustive for anything you might ever possibly need - just find something that works with the formats you expect.